# Kafka producer doesn't write message into kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have this code:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.*;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Main {
    private final static String TOPIC = "rpdc_21596_in";
    private final static String BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS = "server_ip:9092";

    private static KafkaProducer<String, String> createProducer() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "KafkaExampleProducer");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                StringSerializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                StringSerializer.class.getName());

        return new KafkaProducer<>(props);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProducerRecord<String, String> record =
                new ProducerRecord<String, String>(TOPIC, 0, 123L, "fdsfds", "afdasfd");
        KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = createProducer();
        producer.send(record);
        producer.flush();
        producer.close();
    }
}
```

And it doesn't write anything into the topic that I want it to write into.

The topic exists, here's a screenshot from offset explorer:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I get no errors and the program finishes successfully.

Comment: Your image doesn't show anything other than the topic has one partition. It doesn't validate that the end-offset of that partition hasn't updated. Preferably you use `kafka-console-consumer`, and not rely on GUI tools, anyway

Comment: I am telling you with words that there's no updates, I've launched this program a thousand times and there are no new messages.

Comment: I'm just saying the image doesn't add any information to the question. There are other options than calling `.flush()` and `.close()` like `.get()` and passing a callback for when the record is acked.

Comment: from the picture you can verify that i am writing into an existing topic and an existing partition within that topic. so it does add something

Comment: "like .get() and passing a callback for when the record is acked. " could you send a code example?

Comment: Examples are shown in the Javadoc https://kafka.apache.org/30/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html#send(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord,org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Callback)

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks, after adding "get()" I got a TimeoutException saying "Topic rpdc_21596_in not present in metadata after 60000 ms."

Comment: Okay, I changed port to 6667 instead of 9092 and it worked, thanks.

Comment: Topic name seems fine. So, that could mean your bootstrap server address requires authentication or is incorrect. Or that the `advertised.listeners` for the broker is not configured correctly.